# DocuSign API Automatic Populating Tabs not working when using a template

Tags: tabs, docusignapi

I have create a template with the following Data Label: SiteStreet
I have the same named label on page 1 and page 2.
According to the documentation:

[RestAPI](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Automatically%20Populating%20Tabs.htm?Highlight=tabLabel)

it says that if I add the “\*” to the beginning of my tabLabel the value should be copied to all labels throughout the envelope.  This would include both pages and any other documents.

The Envelope is created but not all the tabs are populated.

code:

```
Dim oBody As New StringBuilder


        oBody.Append("<envelopeDefinition xmlns=""http://www.docusign.com/restapi"">")
        oBody.Append("<status>sent</status>")
        oBody.Append("<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template</emailSubject>")
        oBody.Append("<templateId>" & templateId & "</templateId>")

        oBody.Append("<templateRoles>")

        oBody.Append("<templateRole>") '---------------------------------------
        oBody.Append("<name>John Smith</name>")
        oBody.Append("<email>jsmith@gmail.com</email>")
        oBody.Append("<roleName>Consultant</roleName>")

        oBody.Append("<tabs>")
        oBody.Append("<textTabs>")
        oBody.Append("<text>")
        oBody.Append("<tabLabel>\\*SiteStreet</tabLabel>")
        oBody.Append("<value>1000 NE 1st Street</value>")
        oBody.Append("</text>")
        oBody.Append("</textTabs>")
        oBody.Append("</tabs>")

        oBody.Append("</templateRole>") '---------------------------------------
```

I have ensured that the tabs are associated with the "Consultant" template role.  But only one tab get populated.

Is the prefix different in XML vs JSON for the "\*"?
Also the template has In-Person signers, but I wouldn't think that would make a difference.

Comment: sample of the XML that is being posted... unable to add to this post because it is too long for a comment

Comment: code `<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
  <status>sent</status>
  <emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template</emailSubject>
  <templateId>47a30cca-b571-4d16-9254-85c9bfb6764e</templateId>
  <templateRoles>
    <templateRole>
      <name>Shane</name>
      <email>Shaneo@gmail.com</email>
      <roleName>Consultant</roleName>
      <tabs>
        <textTabs>
        <text>
          <tabLabel>\\*SiteStreet</tabLabel>
          <value>1000 NE 1st Street</value>
        </text>
      </textTabs>
      </tabs>
    </templateRole>`

Comment: code continued: `<templateRole>
      <name>Shane Olvera</name>
      <email>Shaneo@gmail.com</email>
      <roleName>ConsultantHost1</roleName>
      <inPersonSignerName>Ben Sith</inPersonSignerName>
    </templateRole>
    <templateRole>
      <name>Shane Olvera</name>
      <email>Shaneo@gmail.com</email>
      <roleName>ConsultantHost2</roleName>
      <inPersonSignerName>Anna Smith</inPersonSignerName>
    </templateRole>
  </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your 'data population scope' setting on the DocuSign account is set to 'envelope' as opposed to 'document'. Additional details available: https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00003842

Comment: I changed my setting within my profile to "Data Population Scope: Envelope" but still unable to have the same tabLabel populate on multiple pages.